# Change in Reputation

Tags: bug, reputation

On 21st March 2016, I had 2160 reputation, but next day I saw, and it said 2132.

In my recent achievement, I cannot see any negative marking, which led to low reputation.

Is this a bug? Who can resolve this issue?

P.S. I know about audit log, but it is not showing reputation which I lose. + I know how reputation works, and there is no negative points I received in the last 2 days.

Comment: ".. no negative points I received **in the last 2 days**" – *any* post that gets deleted, no matter how long ago, will immediately deduce points. I see a number of "-10 – user deleted" remarks in your rep overview.

Comment: No, there were no post deleted, plus if that had happened then I could've seen that in recent achievement dialogue, but there isn't anything

Comment: "Recent"? But that is exactly what I was saying above. "-10    Jan 19  -10  19:35  removed User was removed ([learn more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed))", on your [rep table](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4414557/gaurav-dave?tab=reputation).

Comment: It was on 10 jan, and that deduction I'm aware of, and there is a deduction of 28, which is different to what happened on Jan.